# in Login Form (An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Project.exe)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hello Every One I have an issue in My Project>Login Form

when i Click Login it gives me this Error

And here is ScreenShots for the Exceptions and Problem

[CLS_Login.cs LOGIN CLASS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx0gl.jpg)

[DataAccessLayer.cs  Access data from the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgiM8.jpg)

i use Visual studio 2015
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Microsoft SQL Server Express

Comment: When posting code please post as text in the question and only then post an image if you think it adds value to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataAccessLayer constructor creates a local sqlconnection variable, instead of assigning the instance-level sqlconnection variable. Remove the datatype in the declaration in the DataAccessLayer constructor to turn it into just an assignment.